# How to mock a method inside concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, activesupport-concern

I have `FooConcern` and `BarService` as follows:

```rb
module FooConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def notify_slack(message)
    # send message to slack
  end
end
```

```rb
class BarService
  include FooConcern

  def run
    # do some stuff
    message = 'blah, blah'
    notify_slack(message)
  end
end
```

How can I write to mock `notify_slack` so I don't actually call slack API when I run Rspec test for `BarService#run` ?

```rb
RSpec.describe BarService do
  describe 'run' do
    subject { described_class.new.run }

    it do
      # some tests on things other than notifying slack
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [allow](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-99/docs/method-stubs) to mock that method.

```
RSpec.describe BarService do
   describe 'run' do
     subject { described_class.new }

     it do
       allow(subject).to receive(:notify_slack).and_return(true)
       # some tests on things other than notifying slack
       subject.run
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! You saved my day.